# Split distinct values in a column into multiple columns

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I want to create a DataFrame that breaks down the genres of movies into separate columns, with each individual genre column having a value of 1 for movies that are of that genre.

from this [movie dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0QDLB.jpg)

to this
[dataframe with distinct genre column created, 1 for true and 0 for false](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NojrN.png)

I'm using Databricks PySpark.
many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would first get the unique values of the dataframe column in a list, and then iterate over the list.
The name of dataframe is taken as df here

```
unique_vals = df.select('genres').distinct().rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x).collect()
```

Now lets iterate over the list

```
df1=df
for i in unique_vals:
    df2 = df1.withColumn(i,F.when(F.col('centroid')==i,1).otherwise(0))
    df1=df2
df2.show()
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This work when I change the '==' to '.contains()'

Answer (score 0):

I think this would work

```
df.groupby().pivot('genres').agg(lit(1)).fillna(0)
```